# What methods have been used to distinguish the text between the two strands of The Neverending Story?

Tags: german-language, publishing, textual-history, michael-ende, the-neverending-story

I've owned two copies of Michael Ende's *The Neverending Story* in my life - both English translations, one paperback with a blue cover, one hardback with a red cover inside the dustcover. Both of them clearly distinguished in the text between the parts of the story happening in the Outer World (Bastian in the school attic, etc.) and the parts happening in Fantastica. It's important to distinguish them, because sometimes the nipping back and forth is on the order of paragraphs rather than chapters.

- The first used ordinary Roman text for the Fantastica parts and italics for the Outer World parts.
- The second used green text for the Fantastica parts (very dark green - I thought it was black at first) and red text for the Outer World parts.

**What other methods have been used to distinguish the text of the two strands of the story?** (Answers from different translations, audiobooks, Braille copies, etc. are also acceptable, if that's OK without making the question too broad.)

Comment: The first print of the book (Thienemann, 1979) features red and (light) green colours, as I‘m happy to prove. Apparently, the 2004 revised edition is not a coloured print. I don’t have that one though, but I‘ll double-check.

Comment: I'm curious about this too, actually - I'm on hold for the audiobook at the library and I'll mention what they do once I start listening.

Comment: My ebook version uses red text for Bastian's POV and green text for the story in Fantastica